# Dynatree: Prevent parent nodes from being selected by default, using select mode 3 (hierarchical)

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I am using Dynatree with select mode "3", which enables a hierarchical selection mode.

When my tree renders, all nodes that have children render as selected by default. Leaf nodes render unselected by default. If I start manually selecting nodes, the tree behaves as expected.

How can I force *all* nodes to be unchecked by default?

Notes:

- Dynatree 1.2.1 RC3
- Tree starts out empty and is programatically constructed using "addChild()"
- It makes no difference if I explicitly add "selected: false" when building my nodes.
- Have not tried pre-constructing the entire structure.

Thoughts?

Comment: sounds like a bug. the best would be to open an issue at googlecode and provide a sample

Comment: Reported as issue 288: http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/issues/detail?id=288

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the selection was occurring as a result of building my tree via code. When I call *.addChild()* to create a root level node the node is not selected. When I call *.addChild()* and add a child to it, it then becomes selected.

To fix this, I manually call *.select(false)* on the parent after adding the child.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Dynatree or if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    $("#tree").dynatree("getRoot").visit(function(node) {
        node.expand(false);
    });
```

I know this solution is too late for you, but I am posting this so that it helps others who are facing the same issue.